# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField not updating variable

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am struggling with the `DropdownButtonFormField` where when you change the value it runs the `onChange` function with the updated value. However, once the `onChange` finishes the value variable seems to reset itself meaning it never changes.

This is a cut-down version of the full form:

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController assetGroupNameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController assetGroupDescriptionController = new TextEditingController();
  String assetGroupTypeController;

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProgressDialog pr;

    assetGroupNameController.text = widget.assetGroup.name;
    assetGroupDescriptionController.text = widget.assetGroup.description;
    assetGroupTypeController = widget.assetGroup.type;
    
   return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          elevation: 13.0,
          child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
            value: assetGroupTypeController,
            items: assetGroupTypes.map((f) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: f['key'],
                child: new Text(f['text']),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              typeDropdownChange(value);
            })
          )
        )
   );

 }
```

```
  void typeDropdownChange(value) {
    setState(() {
      assetGroupTypeController = value;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the controller directly to `value` parameter of `DropdownButtonFormField` and you have string value for `DropdownMenuItem`. You should be storing the same data type value. Check below example and modify your code accordingly

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Center(
          child: new MyDropDown(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDropDown({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDropDownState createState() => _MyDropDownState();
}

class _MyDropDownState extends State<MyDropDown> {
  String selected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: selected,
      items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
          .map((label) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text(label),
        value: label,
      ))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() => selected = value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The way I'm building the items is fine because it passes through a string value. I think my problem is at the top of my Widget build() I'm setting dropdown controller to equal whats in my widget.assetGroup.type which is never updated